# Database design for a riding with an variable number of candidates

Tags: sql, database, database-design

So, I have a riding table, and a candidate table. Each riding can have up to 12 candidates running in it, and each candidate has their own individual result. In addition I have a polling division table, which is similar to the riding table, except that several hundred divisions usually share the same set of candidates.

I'm having trouble making a database design out of this. Currently, I have 2 columns per candidate, one of which stores an ID into the candidates table, and the other the result. The ridings table  looks like this:

```
(riding_id INTEGER, name TEXT, cand0_id INTEGER, cand0_result INTEGER ... cand11_id INTEGER, cand11_result INTEGER)
```

The polling division table is similar.

The candidates table looks like this:

```
(cand_id INTEGER, riding_id INTEGER, name TEXT)
```

If a riding or poll has less than 12 candidates then that set of columns is empty. However, this is unwieldy to work with because it requires massive queries to get every column that I need and a giant join on the candidates table.

If I had just the ridings, I could just use the riding id in the candidates table for the relation, but there are also several hundred polling divisions a candidate is also associated with, meaning that I run into the "ton of columns" problem again if I want to do the same thing with polling divisions.

Is there a sane way to lay out my data?

Comment: Please add some sample data to understand you more clearly. A few rows will go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to maintain a categorical design, and avoid the desire to have a design that has 'across' columns.  Your design should include views that pivot the data into other layout forms needed for reporting purposes.

Based on your question and speculation of polling management

```
candidates
----------
candidate_id
name
affiliation_id
etc...

ridings
-------
riding_id
name
etc...

riding_candidates
-----------------
riding_candidate_id
riding_id
candidiate_id
result

polling_divisions
-----------------
polling_division_id
name
etc...

polling_division_candidates
---------------------------
polling_division_candidate_id
polling_division_id
candidate_id
detail... (specific to division+candidate combination)
etc...
```